# NgZones and modified after checked error in Angular 4

Tags: angular

At the core, zones sort of monkey-patch asynchronous APIs and allow hooks for executing callbacks while entering / leaving the async code [This is all I could understand, execution context regarding zones does not make any sense to me, seems like a misnomer, perhaps I am dumb.]

Angular extends zone, to create NgZone, adding functionality for detecting changes [usually caused due to async code] and pushes model changes to the view in the monkey patched hooks. [This is great idea! I follow till here.]

And then I come across the modified after checked error at times. And it is all over the documentation [perhaps, related to differences between reactive and template driven forms as well? ] Okay. I don't get this.

At the core, I am trying to understand if there is certain rule obeyed by angular, to not allow changes after passes of hooks being executed? I see that I need to wait a tick to modify a view-bound model in the ngAfterViewInit lifecyle method as well, and if I don't, modified after checked error is thrown. I don't know why.

Why and how this works the way it works? why the wait?

For instance : check this plunk updating a bound property once composed:

https://plnkr.co/edit/VVWg4w1yRGUR1Mnte7co?p=preview

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
 this.msg = `I just want you to check the console!!`;
}
```

I know angular forbids changes to the view once data has been composed, hence it throws the changed after composed error viewable in console. But why? And how does it work internally? If I wait a tick, probably put the above code in setTimeout(fn,0)[ again, monkey patched version would run], and wait until the call stack[ or zone stack? ] clears, it will execute without any error. Why would angular only allow me to modify in the next tick?

Comment: You did a good job trying to explain your issue - but I still have some problems really understanding what you wonder about. Can you maybe provide a concrete example?

Comment: @FredrikLundin Hi, I tried expounding  to the best of my ability.  Please let me know if that is okay. - Thanks

Comment: I'm honestly not sure why this is. There is a little documentation on the official docs under "Lifecycle Hooks" (https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#abide-by-the-unidirectional-data-flow-rule), but not a lot. A detail I found is that this check is disabled when running in prod mode (`enableProdMode()`) is run on bootstrap). Sorry I can't be of more help

Comment: @FredrikLundin indeed! I just spent a day hunting why [ I know, I went overboard], but yes, in addition to what you said, this also often causes problems while testing template driven forms, I hit a roadblock twice trying to wrap my head around it and couldn't figure out yet. Thanks !

Comment: Yea, I also found these tests in the source code. Doesn't help much though: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9a7f5d580fbb377be39cfaa518f55f4825f20bf5/packages/core/test/view/component_view_spec.ts#L139, https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5d4b36f80f295455f4250c4257462b22ce6b3372/packages/core/test/linker/change_detection_integration_spec.ts#L1156 and https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d108479d84f00ddb29f02d8a19885793a30b94b4/packages/core/test/view/embedded_view_spec.ts#L167

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17815